# ion-select select/unselect all options

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

How to provide an option to select all the option at once in an ion-select element. Below is my code.

```
 <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Primary Data</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="primaryData">
        <ion-option>10</ion-option>
        <ion-option>11</ion-option>
        <ion-option>13</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-select-with-select-all-option/62410/7

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do the following:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Primary Data</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="primaryData">
        <ion-option value="All">All</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="10">10</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="11">11</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="13">13</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Then inside your component.ts file just check which option is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Tried your solution but the onClick of 'All' is not selecting all the options.

Comment: Are you wanting it to visually represent all the options being clicked?

Comment: yes correct. I want display all the options clicked. I am also using multiple="true".

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-select-with-select-all-option/62410/7 - as Sajeetharan suggested

Comment: @Sajeetharan: I am able to get the selected options but unable to show all the options as checked